# Serving static assets from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I am running a Rails 3.0.9 app on Heroku's Cedar stack and have S3 serving static assets. In my production.rb file, there was a config set to:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

If I change this to true, will it serve cached content quicker, or should I leave it as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From rails guide:

config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won´t be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Considering that Heroku doesn't use a web server like Nginx or Apache, I'll leave it to true. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Rafal is not strictly correct as essentially it comes down to what stack and what version of Rails you choose to run in your application.

With Rails **3.0** on the **Bamboo** stack there is a Varnish cache which sits in front of the Thin processes that Heroku run.  This caches any static assets and returns them without hitting your application.

With Rails **3.0** on the **Cedar** stack there is no Varnish cache.  Therefore all requests will be hitting your Rails process regardless of whether they are static or not.

With Rails **3.1** which should be on **Cedar** Heroku will try to run a `rake assets:precompile` as part of the slug compilation process.  If this fails for any reason it will inject some code into your slug meaning that static assets are compiled and served at at run time.

There is a Rails **3.1** document on the dev center which is particularly useful regarding this:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31

So, if you're looking for the correct setting bear this in mind.  However, before you do that, notice that Heroku will alter this setting as they see fit when you do your deploy, so any setting that you do put in will be overwritten anyway during the slug compilation.  Therefore it doesn't really matter what you put in here.

(and for the record, Heroku uses Nginx, you just don't tend to see it)